# Compare one column in excel to another column in excel and find duplicate values

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I was just wondering if there was an easy way in Excel to complete the following task:

In my Excel spreadsheet I have two tabs.  One tab represents one database and the other tab represents a different database.  I have a column of data that is 1500+ rows long from my first database(tab) that looks like this:

[image]

In the other tab, I have another column that is similar to the above column.  My goal is to be able to compare the above column to the other column in the separate tab, and search for duplicate values.

So for example the first code in the above column is 00064.  It would search the specified column in the separate tab for the code 00064.  If it finds it I would need to be alerted or have it logged somehow.  Then it would move on to the next code, 00368 and repeat the process for every cell inside that column.  I hope this makes sense.  Please feel free to ask any questions you may have for further clarification.

My desired outcome is to ween out the duplicate values but I am not sure how to go about this because due to the length of my columns, manual comparisons would take quite some time.  If there is a macro that could accomplish this it would make my life so much easier.

I greatly appreciate any help that can be offered.

Thank you!

-Dave

Comment: There are any number of `MATCH`, `LOOKUP` or `COUNTIF` functions that will locate the duplicates. Conditional formatting will identify them. If you want a macro to do this you should decide on what action(s) you want the macro to perform when it finds a duplicate. Get started on the code by designing the primary loops and identifying method(s). When you run into trouble you can come back with a full picture of what you hope to accomplish and post your problem code segments.

Comment: I just included the mysql to signify that my data was from a mysql database.  Maybe it wasn't the correct thing to do but I was thinking someone may be able to show me a way to do it in the database itself.  Although I didn't explicitly say that and I apologize.  I actually did think of another way to accomplish this in mysql outside of Excel.  This was after the fact though.  The solution in mysql was to load both databases into my localhost and run queries to find the duplicates.  I know this explanation isn't directly related to my question but could help if encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for VBA here. In the first cell of your second column (B1) of your first tab use a `countif` formula:

```
=countif(tab2!A:A, A1)
```

Copy this formula down so it is next to every populated cell in Column `A`. This will return the number of records in Tab2 that are equal to A1 in your first tab. Look for anything > 0 to find things that have a match, or things > 2 for duplicates.

You can extend this with an if statement like

```
=if(countif(tab2!A:A, A1)>2, "Duplicate", countif(tab2!A:A, A1)=1, "Only one Match", "No Match"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was able to search for duplicates very easily using this method.

Answer (score 2):

This does not require the use of a macro. I would use a VLOOKUP formula. If an exact match is found between the columns it will return the columns value. If no match is found the cell will read #N/A.

An example of the formula that compares the cell A1 on Sheet1 to the column A on Sheet2 looks like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:A,1,)
```

[Here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) is documentation on how to use this formula.

Comment: I had to do a little extra research using this method but it worked like I charm!  I actually used both of your answers and compared the results to ensure that the number of duplicates was accurate.  Thank you very much!  I would accept both of your answers if I could!